# How can I express range validity in Idris?

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I am trying to model a simple survey form in Idris and currently struggling with validating user input, which comes as a string, w.r.t. to the type of questions asked.

Currently I have the following types:

```
data Question : Type where
  QCM : {numOptions : Nat}
      -> (question : String) 
      -> (qcmOptions : Vect numOptions String)
      -> (expected : Fin numOptions)
      -> Question

data Answer : (q : Question) -> Type where
   AnswerQCM : (option : Fin n) -> Answer (QCM {numOptions = n } q opts exp)

total 
isCorrectAnswer : (q : Question ) -> Answer q -> Bool
isCorrectAnswer (QCM {numOptions} question qcmOptions expected) (AnswerQCM option) = option == expected


data IsAnswer : (s : String) -> (q : Question) -> Type where
     ValidQCM : (option : Fin n) -> IsAnswer s (QCM {numOptions = n } q opts exp)

notInRange : (num : Fin n) -> { auto prf : GT numOptions n } 
           -> IsAnswer s (QCM {numOptions} q opts exp) -> Void
notInRange num x = ?notInRange_rhs
```

I don't see how to write the `notInRange`function which should be a proof that some number may not be a valid answer to a multiple-choice question survey: This number should be in the correct range for the number of options offered within the question.

More generally , I want to write a `readAnswer` function that would look like:

```
readAnswer : (s : String) -> (q : Question) -> Dec (IsAnswer s q)
readAnswer s (QCM question qcmOptions expected) = ?readAnswer_rhs_1
```

It seems I am having a hard-time finding the `contra` part of `Dec` because my types do not correctly express the constraints I want in such a way that some of them can be proved uninhabited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, answer to your question is pretty big. You have several design problems. I won't just paste result code. Intead I'll try to explain what's going on and what are problems in your current approach. And maybe my solution is not exactly what you want (and maybe you even don't need exactly what you want) but I hope it helps you.

One big problem is in your `isCorrectAnswer` function. It returns `Bool` and `Bool` is bad for proving because compiler doesn't know much from value of `Bool`. If you want more proving power, you should use `Refl` instead of `True/False`. Same situation with `Maybe` and `Dec`. If it's enough for you to have `Maybe` then ok, but if you want your implementation be provable you should using `Dec` instead of `Maybe`. And once you're decided to use `Dec` in your function, all functions you are using and calling from it should also contain more provable information.

Good start for thinking process is to think about having some function like:

```
isCorrectAnswer : (q: Question) -> (a: Answer q) -> expected q = option a
```

Unfortunately, this function can't exist because of two problems.

1. It's a proof and proof is what is always true. If you have arbitrary `Question` and `Answer` it's not always true that expected answer is exactly that what was given. Thus, you should transform this function into data type with such property. It's just a general approach.
2. Well, you can't even write `expected` function for your `Question` data type in current situation. Maybe someone can but I tried and failed. This `expected` function is not the name of corresponding field in your current implementation. And `numOptions` is some internal thing for `Question`. It's not visible from outside without pattern matching. So it's good thing to parametrize `Question` over vector length.

To solve 2 I'll transform your data types a little in the next way:

```
record Question (numOptions : Nat) where
    constructor QCM
    question   : String
    qcmOptions : Vect numOptions String
    expected   : Fin  numOptions

record Answer (q : Question n) where
    constructor AnswerQCM
    option : Fin n
```

So now property can look like this:

```
data IsCorrectAnswer : (q : Question n) -> (a: Answer q) -> Type where
   IsCorrect : {q: Question n} 
            -> {a: Answer q} 
            -> expected q = option a 
            -> IsCorrectAnswer q a
```

And here is simple deciding procedure for it:

```
isCorrectAnswer : (q : Question n) -> (a: Answer q) -> Dec (IsCorrectAnswer q a)
isCorrectAnswer (QCM  _ _ expected) (AnswerQCM option) =
    case decEq expected option of
        Yes prf   => Yes (IsCorrect prf)
        No contra => No (\(IsCorrect prf) => contra prf)
```

In your question you want property between `String` and `Question` while I implemented between `Answer` and `Question`. So now theorically you can just lookup this string in `qcmOptions`, find `Fin` index, transform it to answer and get `Dec` for `IsCorrectAnswer`. Well, sort of. Except it turns out to be very very non-trivial. Just because of reasons why you can't prove theorem you want.

There is **nothing** to connect `s: String` with `(option : Fin n)` in your data type. Probably, several additional properties and data types can help. But simpler solution is to make your `IsAnswer` property contain more information using [`Elem` property](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/674c2141797b447bfcafd497b927637dacdb7ec3/libs/base/Data/Vect.idr#L599) for `Vect`. And here is final implementation almost identical to `isCorrectAnswer`:

```
data IsAnswer : (s : String) -> (q : Question n) -> Type where
    ValidQCM : {q: Question n} -> Elem s (qcmOptions q) -> IsAnswer s q

readAnswer : (s : String) -> (q: Question n) -> Dec (IsAnswer s q)
readAnswer s (QCM _ options _) = case isElem s options of
    Yes prf   => Yes (ValidQCM prf)
    No contra => No (\(ValidQCM prf) => contra prf)
```

You can notice that I didn't use `isCorrectAnswer` here and I probably can't because of problems I've mentioned earlier. But I don't need to use it here. Simpler solution is better.

**P.S.** Sorry for wall of text, I've may been write shorter answer but I hope in such way this answer can clarify more things to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the "wall of text". I have tried to give more thought to the problem and came up with the following code: https://gist.github.com/abailly/ee151106ced526842e127dbe6f5746cb Note that the `numOptions` parameter is specific to the QCM questions hence should not be part of the `Question` type definition: The overall idea is to model a quizz where different kind of questions need different kind of answers. The `isCorrectAnswer` function is not used anymore in `readAnswer` and I have `validateAnswer` function that constructs a proof of the answer.

Comment: The one thing that is bugging me now is: How do create proper contradictions? The generic `VOID` I use is unsatisfying, if only because it is not total. I hit a wall when trying to define `tooLarge`: I would like to use `contra` but I need a proof  of `LTE num ub` to apply to the one given, which I somehow have as an implicit `ubok` but I can't make the connection between the `num` and the `answer` parameters...

Comment: @insitu Yes, using `VOID` is not good because you're actually not proving anything. It's like using `believe_me`. One of the problems, as I said, in using `Maybe`-like functions. When you're using `parsePositive` (and I don't know where this function really is) you're working with `Maybe` and `Maybe` doesn't have any proof information. Thus it becomes very difficult to proof something. Ideally `parsePositive` function should return additionally proof of the fact that parsed integer is `>= 0`. And then using that information you can probably prove more.

Comment: Another thing that is not convenient is that there're not so many standard proofs. Probably you can start with implementing your own `InRange` properties similar to `Elem` for vectors and then you can implement separately all required theorems for it. But this is most likely topic for another specific question, for example, how to prove something like this: `tooSmall : (contra : LTE lb num -> Void) -> lb -> num -> Void` (one problem with your `tooSmall` function is that `LTE` is for `lb` and some unknown `num` and there's no connection between `num` and `expected`).

Comment: Thanks again for your insightful comments, I think they helped me make great progress in deepening my understanding of Idris and dependent types. I completed the quizz program I was aiming at (but did not incorporate yet your remarks and suggestions): http://lpaste.net/353913