# Idris Dec vs Maybe

Tags: error-handling, idris, theorem-proving, option-type

What kind of things can one express with `Dec` and not with `Maybe` in **Idris**?

Or in other words: When should one choose `Dec` and when `Maybe`?

Comment: Maybe you'll find it helpful or interesting reading the definition of the [`isItJust : (v : Maybe a) -> Dec (IsJust v)`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/prelude/Prelude/Maybe.idr#L38-L48) function from the standard library which "decides whether a 'Maybe' is 'Just'".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I told a little bit about this in the answer to the [one recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974540/how-can-i-express-range-validity-in-idris).
There're two reasons for using `Dec`:

1. You want to prove things and have more guarantees from the implementation.
2. You want your function to run in finite time.

Regarding **1**. Consider this function for `Nat` equality:

```
natEq : (n: Nat) -> (m: Nat) -> Maybe (n = m)
natEq Z Z = Just Refl
natEq Z (S k) = Nothing
natEq (S k) Z = Nothing
natEq (S k) (S j) = case natEq k j of
    Nothing   => Nothing
    Just Refl => Just Refl
```

You can write tests for this function and see if it works. But compiler can't stop you at compile-time from writing `Nothing` in every case. Such function still will be compilable. `Maybe` is some sort of *weak* proof. It means, if you return `Just` then you're able to find answer and we are good but if you return `Nothing` it means nothing. You just can't find answer. But when you're using `Dec` you can't just return `No`. Because if you're returning `No` it means that you can actually prove that there is no answer. So rewriting `natEq` into `Dec` will require more effort from you as a programmer but implementation is now more robust:

```
zeroNotSucc : (0 = S k) -> Void
zeroNotSucc Refl impossible

succNotZero : (S k = 0) -> Void
succNotZero Refl impossible

noNatEqRec : (contra : (k = j) -> Void) -> (S k = S j) -> Void
noNatEqRec contra Refl = contra Refl

natEqDec : (n: Nat) -> (m: Nat) -> Dec (n = m)
natEqDec Z Z = Yes Refl
natEqDec Z (S k) = No zeroNotSucc
natEqDec (S k) Z = No succNotZero
natEqDec (S k) (S j) = case natEqDec k j of
    Yes Refl  => Yes Refl
    No contra => No (noNatEqRec contra)
```

Regarding **2**. `Dec` stands for *decidability*. It means that you can return `Dec` only for decidable problems, i.e. problems that can be solved in finite time. You can solve `Nat` equality in finite time because you'll eventually fall into case with `Z`. But for something difficult, like, check whether given `String` represents *Idris* program that calculates first 10 prime numbers, you can't.